# ArcPress not sizing Print ActiveView correctly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, printing, arcpress

I am not sure this is exactly an ArcPress issue, but it is where I am at. I am on 10.1, SP1. I am sending a map to a HP DesignJet T1300ps printer. The printer is supported by ArcPress.

When I use the PrintActiveView ArcPressVB_Net-Addin2010 sample code from the developer kit, (the exact same code sample is on ESRI'S site) the code does function, though it does not size the plot correctly. The map size is 20.25 x 24 with the output being 13 x 19.

My first question is has anyone had success with this code printing the correct map size?

In attempting a work around I have worked with the Page and Paper properties in an attempt to set the custom page size with ArcPress.

My second question is has anyone been able to manipulate the Page and Paper properties in working with ArcPress to get the correct map size printed?

Another question, on the code:

docArcPressPrinter.AutoSelectDriverByName(My.ArcMap.ThisApplication.Paper.PrinterName)

Is this looking for the actual name (type) of the printer: HP Designjet T1300ps?

I have inserted the code sample I am working with.

---

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
 Imports System.Drawing
 Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto
 Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Output
 Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry
 Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Display
 Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.OutputExtensions
 Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem
 Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class PrintActiveViewArcPressVB_Net_Addin
 Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()
 'calls the PrintActiveViewVBParameterized function with an argument.
 PrintActiveViewVBParameterized(3)
 End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnUpdate()
 Enabled = My.ArcMap.Application IsNot Nothing
 End Sub

Private Sub PrintActiveViewVBParameterized(ByVal iResampleRatio As Integer)
 'Prints the active view of the document to the default printer using the 
'ArcPress Printer Engine. If the printer is not supported by the ArcPress
 'printer engine's "auto-select" driver selection method, the function exits and
 'no print is made.
 Dim docActiveView As IActiveView = My.ArcMap.Document.ActiveView
 Dim docPrinter As IPrinter
 Dim PrintAndExport As IPrintAndExport = New PrintAndExport
 Dim docArcPressPrinter As IArcPressPrinter
 Dim sNameRoot As String
 Dim iNumPages As Short

docArcPressPrinter = New ArcPressPrinter()
 docPrinter = New ArcPressPrinter()

Try

'Attempt to auto-select a driver based on the printer's name. If no driver can be 
'auto-selected, exit the function and show a message about the failure.
 docArcPressPrinter.AutoSelectDriverByName(My.ArcMap.ThisApplication.Paper.PrinterName)
 If docArcPressPrinter.SelectedDriverId Is Nothing Then
 MessageBox.Show("Cannot auto-select ArcPress Driver for " & My.ArcMap.ThisApplication.Paper.PrinterName & ".", "ArcPress Driver Auto-select Error")
 Exit Sub
 End If

'Pass the newly created ArcPressPrinter to docPrinter.
 docPrinter = docArcPressPrinter
 sNameRoot = "PrintActiveViewArcPressSample"

'using the current printer.
 docPrinter.Paper = My.ArcMap.ThisApplication.Paper

'make sure the paper orientation is set to the orientation matching the current view.
 docPrinter.Paper.Orientation = My.ArcMap.Document.PageLayout.Page.Orientation

'set the spool filename (this is the job name that shows up in the print queue)
 docPrinter.SpoolFileName = sNameRoot

' Find out how many printer pages the output will cover. iNumPages will always be 1 
' unless the user explicitly sets the tiling options in the file->Print dialog. 
If TypeOf My.ArcMap.Document.ActiveView Is IPageLayout Then
 My.ArcMap.Document.PageLayout.Page.PrinterPageCount(docPrinter, 0, iNumPages)
 Else
 'always set the number of pages to 1 for a data view.
 iNumPages = 1
 End If

Dim lCurrentPageNum As Short
 For lCurrentPageNum = 1 To iNumPages Step lCurrentPageNum + 1
 Try
 PrintAndExport.Print(docActiveView, docPrinter, My.ArcMap.Document.PageLayout.Page, lCurrentPageNum, iResampleRatio, Nothing)
 Catch ex As Exception
 MessageBox.Show("Printing cancelled for page " + lCurrentPageNum)
 End Try

Next

Catch ex As Exception
 MessageBox.Show(My.ArcMap.ThisApplication.Paper.PrinterName & " is not a supported printer.", "ArcPress Driver Auto-select Error")
 End Try

End Sub

End Class
```